# Execute ad-hoc script against multiple schemas in PostgreSQL using loops

Tags: postgresql, loops

I have a script in PostgreSQL that looks like this:

```
SET SEARCH_PATH TO "foo";
{...500 lines of script...}

SET SEARCH_PATH TO "bar";
{...500 lines of script...}

SET SEARCH PATH TO "baz";
{...500 lines of script...}

...etc
```

The 500 lines of script are character for character identical for each schema, and there are several schemas.

Is there a way to reduce this to a loop using, say, and array of string values of each schema name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. After reading [this topic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/postgresql-executing-ddl-on-every-schema) on dba.stackexchange, it looks like the general pattern is this:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE _schema text;
BEGIN
FOR _schema IN
  SELECT 'foo' UNION
  SELECT 'bar' UNION
  SELECT 'baz'
LOOP
EXECUTE 'SET LOCAL search_path = "' || _schema || '"';

// Add your SQL scripts here

END LOOP;
END
$do$
```